# Order and OrderDetails

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, ado.net, shopping-cart

If i am going to save a record of OrderDetails, I need the OrderId(foreign key) from the Order table. The question is when saving a record of Order, the OrderId is automatically generated

So how do I refer to that particular OrderId, when inserting a record in OrderDetails? This has confused me so much.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005

**Order Table**

```
OrderId
CustomerId
Date
Total
```

**OrderDetails**

```
OrderDetailId
OrderId
ProductId
Quantity
UnitPrice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will depend on what datatype your OrderID is. Assuming it's an `int` identity, you can call SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the identity of the last added row.

For example

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (CustomerId, Date, Total)
VALUES (@CustomerId, @Date, @Total);

DECLARE @OrderID int
SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Please can you give an example of SCOPE_IDENTITY() and how I should use it

Comment: the problem is that i need to execute the orders query only once but orderdetails many times, in the process the OrderId changes and it gives an error as foeign key doesnt match

Comment: Ok. I assume you're using stored procedures. You should have two separate stored procedures - one for inserting the Order record and one for inserting OrderDetail records. The OrderInsert SP should have an OUTPUT parameter to return the OrderID for you to use with the OrderDetailInsert SP.

Answer (score 2):

for the SCOPE_IDENTITY() please refer the following URL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

http://www.objectreference.net/post/SCOPE_IDENTITY%28%29-return-the-id-from-the-database-on-insert.aspx